# .net-traceprocessing How Can WaitAnalysis Be Used?

Tags: .net-traceprocessing

In the library .net-traceprocessing is a namespace Microsoft.Windows.EventTracing.WaitAnalysis which contains many types related to Wait Analysis. How can that be used? Based on the name it sounds useful. Has anyone experience with that one and has a sample at hand?

I know that there is a WaitClassifcation Graph in WPA. Which events need to be recorded to make this one show up as graph and how useful is that one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'd like to make wait analysis available in our public version, but unfortunately we weren't able to do that for our first public release. As you noticed, we removed the top-level entry point but had not cleaned up other types exposed in that namespace. Apologies for the teaser; we'll remove the other remnants of wait analysis in public surface area.

It would take a bit of work to get this feature made public, but we'll put it on our backlog, and let us know if there's more interest here, and that will help raise the priority.

Comment: Can you show some output of WPA how it looks like? That would help to judge its usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, you needed dispatcher, latency, and disk_io (disk_io might be optional) along with the -stackwalk command for cswitch+readythread+threadcreate+profile

```
xperf -on disk_io+dispatcher+latency -stackwalk cswitch+readythread+threadcreate+profile
```

I'm surprised it's listed, I was told that feature was not for public use, but that was 4-6 years ago too.

And example full command might look like the below section;

```
xperf -on disk_io+dispatcher+latency -f <path to file\xperftrace.etl> -MinBuffers 256 -MaxBuffers 1024 -MaxFile 1024 -FileMode Circular -stackwalk cswitch+readythread+threadcreate+profile
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I have enabled these providers the graph still wont show up. I can enable it via the Window-Select Tables (Experimental) dialog but it looks like it is disabled in the public version.

Comment: Yeah I was surprised it was even mentioned in the api. MIght be a bug and they remove it sadly.